# multi task learning for image classifications

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I am currently working on multi task learning to classify if the image is infected with cancer or not and the second task is to use an image to classify the type of lung cancer

I am using datasets from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mohamedhanyyy/chest-ctscan-images

I have written the codes but i am getting an error when i am trying to train the model

Please help.
Here are my codes:`# This Python 3 environment comes with many helpful analytics libraries installed

## packages

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import cv2
import keras
from numpy import random
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.applications import MobileNet, VGG16, ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report ,confusion_matrix
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
# Input data files are available in the read-only "../input/" directory
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list all files under the input directory

import os

import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('/content/drive/MyDrive/lungcancer.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('/content/')


!pip install tensorflow tensorflow_hub


!ls

# Define paths to the dataset
data_dir = '/content/Data'
train_dir = data_dir + '/train'
validation_dir = data_dir + '/valid'
test_dir = data_dir + '/test'

listImageFilePaths = []
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/content/Data/test/normal'):
    for filename in filenames:
        listImageFilePaths.append( os.path.join(dirname, filename))

print('Total images ', len(listImageFilePaths))

input_shape = (224,224,3)
#num_class = 4

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
   dtype='float32',
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
  rotation_range=10,
   width_shift_range=0.2,
   height_shift_range=0.2,
   shear_range=0.2,
  zoom_range=0.2,
   horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=False


)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
   dtype='float32',
   preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,

)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
   dtype='float32',
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,

)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle = False,
)
validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
)


# Load a pre-trained feature extractor model from TensorFlow Hub
feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/5", trainable=False)

# Create an input layer for the model
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Connect the input layer to the feature extractor
feature_output = feature_extractor(input_layer)

# Define the multi-task head for cancer infection classification
cancer_head = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='cancer_head')(feature_output)


# Define the multi-task head for lung cancer type classification
lung_cancer_head = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='lung_cancer_head')(feature_output)

# Combine the inputs and outputs to create the multi-task model
multi_task_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[cancer_head, lung_cancer_head])


# Compile the multi-task model with appropriate loss functions and metrics
multi_task_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss={'cancer_head': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'lung_cancer_head': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
    metrics={'cancer_head': 'accuracy', 'lung_cancer_head': 'accuracy'}
)


# Train the multi-task model
history = multi_task_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator)


# Evaluate the multi-task model
eval_scores = multi_task_model.evaluate(validation_generator)


# Print the evaluation scores
print("Cancer Infection - Loss:", eval_scores[1])
print("Cancer Infection - Accuracy:", eval_scores[2])
print("Lung Cancer Type - Loss:", eval_scores[3])
print("Lung Cancer Type - Accuracy:", eval_scores[4])`


Error
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b769f3dab356> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Train the multi-task model
----> 2 history = multi_task_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-18-b769f3dab356>", line 2, in <cell line: 2>
      history = multi_task_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1984, in categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5565, in categorical_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,2] labels_size=[32,4]
     [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_23304]
```